# OleDbConnection/Command to DB with locale specific character

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, cultureinfo

I have MS Access DB with table what contains **Columns** which **Names** has Danish characters. e.g. `Døbt`

When program works on PC with Danish location everything works fine, but at PC with Ukrainian location I got error that field `Dжbt` is missing. Seems that char `ø` comes to me from DB as `ж`

Code that fires error at last line:

```
var connection = new OleDbConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=F:\\STAT.MDB";
var table = new DataTable( "NewTable" );
table.Locale = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo( "da-DK" ); 
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter( "SELECT Døbt FROM Table", connection );
adapter.Fill( table );
```

Is there some way to set target Culture for connection or something else?

Comment: try setting your app culture to danish, using [`Thread.CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx)

Comment: already tried, doesn't work...

Comment: @Johnny_D it's funny... But this is service DB and it's impossible to make such architecture changes..

Comment: is it possible to set a specific charset? either on the connectionstring, or on your target system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is not with the connection but with the fact that the machine you are running this on doesn't not use the correct character set, there may be an update you can download that will allow the Ukrainian location settings to read Danish characters